# Changing AJAX request header causes preflight request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, cors

I'm trying to access Woocommerce WordPress based REST API using Javascript and I manage to do so on GET requests that require no special headers.
Yet when adding the `Content-Type` to `application/json` header I keep getting preflight `OPTIONS` requests that are being answered with 401 **despite** getting all the right response headers that allow all the headers.

(In case I'm sending with `text/plain` `Content-Type` I'm getting a 400 response with `"Content, title, and excerpt are empty"`, as it cannot be parsed without `application/json` so it's not an authorization problem, it is demanded in the docs aswell).

An example request :

```
OPTIONS /wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_fXXXXX HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXX.com
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:81
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:81/wc_test.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

And the following is the response :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sat, 22 Oct 2016 20:24:24 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,chrome=1
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <http://XXXXXXXX.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:81
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Encoding: gzip
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Length: 156
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
```

Tried adding specifically `Content-Type` and not `*` to Allow-Headers with no success, with or without the `Access-Control-Max-Age`, etc etc.

It happens specifically for that `application/json`, if I were to change it to `text/plain` it works perfectly.

What could be the problem ? According to the requests it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: Try sending a request with some valid credentials. Add and Authorization header. For instance `Authorization: Basic aHR0cHdhdGNoOmY=`. Another option would be using credentials in the url: `https://user:password@www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products?oauth_consumer_key=ck_fXXXXX`

Comment: @victor175 I'm in no need of Basic Authentication though, when sending GET requests it's all good, oAuth removes the need of Authorization in that process.

Comment: On the server you can forbid or restrict different types of requests, including GET. So obviously you also have authorization problem if you get 401. So you need to authorize in some way.

Comment: @victor175 I get 401 regardless of the authorization, in case I'm sending it with text/plain I'm getting a 400 response with "Content, title, and excerpt are empty" as it cannot be parsed without the Content-Type header apparently.